# How to round floats to scaled integers?

Tags: python, math, floating-point, rounding

to further explain my title: I have an array of floats which I want to round, HOWEVER, I want to round the numbers to a number that isn't the closest integer. For example, let's say I want the numbers to be rounded to the nearest integer that is a multiple of 2. This is what I have:

```
Temp = np.around(data,0)
```

with `data` being an array of floats. The numbers are rounded to the closest integer, but I want them to be rounded to the closest multiple of 2. My goal:

0.9 -> 0

1.1 -> 2

etc.

Thanks!

Comment: Isn't 1 a factor of 2?

Comment: There's not a universal approach to this.. ie, no "round to the nearest Fibonacci number".  Do you specifically want "nearest multiple of 2" or are you only interested in an answer for a general approach?

Comment: Let's say 2 specifically, as I could figure out how to change it if needed from there, @tom10

Comment: Consider `m.round(n/m)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A multiple of two is straightforward:

```
x = np.array([0.9, 1.1, 10.2, 7.4])

2*np.round(x/2)   # array([  0.,   2.,  10.,   8.])
```

But there's not a universal approach to this.  For example there's no obvoius "round to the nearest Fibonacci number".  Consider the formula for multiple of `2` as, given a function `f(x)=2*x`: 1) first apply the inverse of `f` (divide in this case), 2) then `round`, 3) then apply `f` to result.  For this to work, `f` must exist, have an inverse, and the result must also be an `int`; so it only works for a few functions.

Comment: What a great, yet simple and detailed, answer. Thanks a lot, mate, that completely solved my problem!

Comment: @tom10: but many languages do have a "round to nearest even" (a.k.a. "banker's rounding", although bankers generally don't round like that), and a multiple of 2 is by definition even. Is there no way to set the default rounding mode?

Comment: @tom10, no, apparently there is not. Instead, you must apply tricks to get what you want.

Comment: Round to the nearest Fibonacci number will be close to `F(round(log(√5n)/log(φ)))`.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: Banker's rounding is round *ties* to the nearest even, which is not the same thing as round to nearest even. That is, values are rounded to the nearest integer (whether it's even or odd). It's only in the case of a value exactly halfway between two consecutive integers that the even one is chosen.

Comment: @MarkDickinson: you're right, that only happens at ties.

Answer (score 1):

Following is one way of doing it:

```
import math

data = [0.9, 1.1, 10.2, 7.4]

rounded_numbers = []

for num in data:

    rounded_up_num = math.ceil(num)

    if rounded_up_num % 2 == 0:
        rounded_num = rounded_up_num
    else:
        rounded_num = math.floor(num)

    rounded_numbers.append(int(rounded_num))

print rounded_numbers # [0, 2, 10, 8]
```

Comment: Seems like a good approach.  However, the execution will be faster if you only evaluate `math.ceil(num)` once.

Comment: good answer, a bit overly complicated, though, as it resulted in a few errors I had to fix. thanks, though.